# rtl8188eus wireless adapter debian installing error

Tags: debian, wifi

I'm trying to install a realtek rtl8188eu wireless adapter on Debian Stretch.

When I run the `installer.sh` provided by the manufacturer I got this error:

```
/home/us3r011/wifi-adapter/driver/rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/osdep_service.h: In function ‘thread_enter’:/home/us3r011/wifi-adapter/driver/rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/osdep_service.h:1423:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘daemonize’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration] daemonize("%s", name); ^~~~~~~~~
```

I also installed the firmware-realtek and the driver from git via `dkms`.

How can I solve?

Answer (score 1):

Function `daemonize()` has been removed from new kernel version.

You have to download driver source from [TP-Link site](https://static.tp-link.com/2018/201805/20180521/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series7_beta.zip). Then unpack `rtl8188EUS_linux_v5.2.2.4_25483.20171222.zip` and `cd` to unpacked directory. Type `make` and you will got `8188eu.ko`.

Compilation works under Debian Stretch with 4.9.0-9 kernel.

Strikethrough text is obsolete for 4.9 kernel which is contained in Debian Stretch.

<s>Some people has adopted driver for rtl8188/8192 considering API changes in new kernel in his [own git repo](https://github.com/dz0ny/rt8192cu). You have to get this adopted driver and build it.</s>

This question has been already asked in [AskUbuntu Stack Exchange network in this thread](https://askubuntu.com/a/312815).

Comment: It failed here `/home/us3r011/wifi-adapter/rt8192cu/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:1032:22: error: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
  .ndo_select_queue = rtw_select_queue,
`

Comment: @us3r is the problem still actual for you? If yes, i'll try to fix compilation issue.

Comment: Yes the problem is still actual, how can you fix that?

Comment: @us3r I've just fix compilation by patching `os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c b/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c` file in the driver sources. You can apply patch from [paste.bin](https://pastebin.com/QYW7AZ97) and rebuild driver. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, now I'm at work and I don't have the adapter with me, tonight I'll try and I'll let you know the result

Comment: how can I apply this patch?

Comment: @us3r I've just fond best solution and edit my answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks, I'll try tonight and let you know if it works